# Type Error: unbound method get_params() must be called with StandardScaler instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Tags: python, machine-learning, typeerror, data-science

I'm taking an online course on applied machine learning by [EliteDataScience.com](https://elitedatascience.com) and I'm currently stuck on trying to fit the ML model.

[Here](https://github.com/HridayThakkar/Project-1-Data-Science-Real-Estate-Tycoon/blob/master/Module%205%20-%20Model%20Training.ipynb) is the Github link to the source code (The module I'm working on is Module 5: Model Training).

I'm facing a Type Error at the following two lines of code:

```
# List tuneable hyperparameters of our Lasso pipeline
pipelines['lasso'].get_params() 


# Fit and tune model
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Here is the error:

```
Type Error: unbound method get_params() must be called with StandardScaler instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Also, attached is the screenshot of the line of code with the error.

[image: line of code with error]

Comment: What is `pipelines['lasso']`?  Is it an _instance_ of `StandardScaler`, or it is the `StandardScaler` base class?

Comment: @John. I doubt you'd see the error with an instance

Comment: sklearn,preprocessing has a StandardScaler . [get_params](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/base.py#L213) is an instance method of a *parent* class.

Comment: You should report to EliteDataScience.  Try changing `'lasso' : make_pipeline(StandardScaler, Lasso(random_state=123))` to `'lasso' : make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), Lasso(random_state=123))` where `pipelines` is made.

Comment: No screenshots please. Post the full text of the traceback instead.

Comment: I followed what "wwii" suggested and it worked. Thanks, all! @MadPhysicist Sorry about that. Will keep that in mind henceforth.